# Adding values to JSON in Python2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have been tasked with combining data from two different sources into one JSON to be used by a web service. I decided to go with flask which I have found to be so easy to use.
Anyway, I am retrieving JSON that looks like this ( via urlib2 )....

```
[
    [{
        "timestamp": 1474088400000,
        "errors": 1018831,
        "errorTotal": 72400021,
        "errorTotal2": 0.013022892930509898,
        "business": 4814994,
        "breakdown": [{
            "type": "type1",
            "count": 603437
        }, {
            "type": "type2",
            "count": 256187
        }]
    }]
]
```

All I am trying to do is add a new key pair under "breakdown", specifically "type3", so the JSON object looks like this...

```
[
    [{
        "timestamp": 1474088400000,
        "errors": 1018831,
        "errorTotal": 72400021,
        "errorTotal2": 0.013022892930509898,
        "business": 4814994,
        "breakdown": [{
            "type": "type1",
            "count": 603437
        }, {
            "type": "type2",
            "count": 256187
        }, {
            "type": "type3",
            "count": 4533
        }]
    }]
]
```

I thought treating it like key pairs in a list would be the way to go but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like that's a list, could maybe append to it in python with `d[0][0]['breakdown'].append({"type": "type3", "count": 4533})`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read the json into Python objects:

```
data = json.loads(jsonstring)
```

Then get to the object to be modified. The data looks like `[ [ {... 'breakdown': ...} ] ]`, so it is a list of lists of dictionaries. I guess you want all of them:

```
for d in data:
    for dd in d:
        d['breakdown'].append({"type": "type3", "count": 4533})
```

Then convert it back to json:

```
update_json = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the `json` string

   ```
   json_data = json.loads(json_string)
   ```
2. Iterate over the object and `append` to the `"breakdown"` key

   ```
   for item in json_data:
       for json_dict in item:
           json_dict["breakdown"].append({"type": "type3", "count": 4533})
   ```
3. Convert it back to the `JSON` string

   ```
   json_string = json.dumps(json_data)
   ```